# Converting JSON document to Google Chart format

Tags: javascript, formatting, elasticsearch

I'm fairly new to Javascript and my situation is this:
I'm using Google Charts to visualize some data and the data is contained in Elasticsearch.

I'm querying the data with an Ajax command however the data that is returned is not usable in Google Charts in its current format.

The query returns data like this:

`{
took: 5
timed_out: false
_shards: {
total: 5
successful: 5
failed: 0
}
hits: {
total: 11
max_score: 1
hits: [
{
_index: inventory
_type: on_hand
_id: 4
_score: 1
_source: {
warehouse_id: 107
date: 03-28-2013
lane: M01
routes: 383
}
}`

I need to have it formatted like this for Google Charts:

```
{
  "cols": [
        {"id":"","label":"Lane","type":"string"},
        {"id":"","label":"Routes","type":"number"}
      ],
  "rows": [
        {"c":[{"v":"M01"},{"v":4657}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"M02"},{"v":4419}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"M03"},{"v":4611}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"M04"},{"v":4326}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"M05"},{"v":4337}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"M06"},{"v":5363}]}
      ]
}
```

While I don't expect someone to write the code for me, I would really appreciate if someone could give me a good starting point for pulling out the needed data, and adding in the proper formatting such as `"cols": [...` and `"rows":[...` etc.  Thank you!

EDIT:

I was able to run an updated query which returns the results in a valid JSON format:

```
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 7,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "wcs",
      "_type" : "routes",
      "_id" : "4",
      "_score" : 1.0, "_source" : {"lane":"M04","routes":"102"}
    }, {
      "_index" : "wcs",
      "_type" : "routes",
      "_id" : "5",
      "_score" : 1.0, "_source" : {"lane":"M03","routes":"143"}
    }, {
      "_index" : "wcs",
      "_type" : "routes",
      "_id" : "1",
      "_score" : 1.0, "_source" : {"lane":"M07","routes":"80"}
    }, {
      "_index" : "wcs",
      "_type" : "routes",
      "_id" : "6",
      "_score" : 1.0, "_source" : {"lane":"M02","routes":"157"}
    }, {
      "_index" : "wcs",
      "_type" : "routes",
      "_id" : "2",
      "_score" : 1.0, "_source" : {"lane":"M06","routes":"101"}
    }, {
      "_index" : "wcs",
      "_type" : "routes",
      "_id" : "7",
      "_score" : 1.0, "_source" : {"lane":"M01","routes":"105"}
    }, {
      "_index" : "wcs",
      "_type" : "routes",
      "_id" : "3",
      "_score" : 1.0, "_source" : {"lane":"M05","routes":"160"}
    } ]
  }
}
```

However the JSON document required actually needs to be exactly as I've shown in my original post for Google Charts to be able to use it.  The `"lane"` and `"routes"` values need to be extracted from the returned data (shown just above) and formatted as the JSON doc in the original post.  Thank you again.

Comment: It seems that they're two different object definitions altogether: the property names are not even the same. How are you supposed to infer the properties?

Comment: Can't you have the server respond with proper JSON? The format you say you're getting is not very js-friendly.

Comment: The query results still aren't valid JSON. Getting closer though. [Here is a gist](https://gist.github.com/dinjas/d33f89982a326f76235a) with the JSON fixed. [Here is a JSON validator](http://zaach.github.io/jsonlint/) you can use to make sure JSON is valid and to format it.

Comment: I wanted to note that the title is *very* misleading. What you are trying to do is not *formatting* JSON, it's restructuring your data structure, which is a JavaScript object in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do something like:

```
var json = {
  "took": 2,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 7,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "wcs",
        "_type": "routes",
        "_id": "4",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "lane": "M04",
          "routes": "102"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};

var data = {};
data.cols = [
    {
        "id": "",
        "label": "Lane",
        "type": "string"
    },
    {
        "id": "",
        "label": "Routes",
        "type":"number"
    }
];
data.rows = [
    {
        "c": [
            {
                "v": json.hits.hits[0]._source.lane
            },
            {
                "v": json.hits.hits[0]._source.routes
            }
        ]
    }
];

console.log(data);
```

Comment: Hi, I'm attempting to use this code, since it looks like essentially what I'd need to do. Its not working, possibly due to single-quotes being omitted around the brackets and braces?  I think its a matter of syntax at this point.  Thanks.

Comment: I noticed that the query response you posted isn't valid JSON, which will cause `JSON.parse` call to fail. Getting those results as a JSON object would probably be the first step. You can log out the contents of a JSON object in the Chrome Debugger `console.log(data);` [This link](http://www.json.org/js.html) might be helpful.

Comment: I updated my answer to handle your new response example. You should be able to cut/paste that directly into Chrome debugger to test it out. I just assigned the JSON response directly to a var assuming that you have it in a var already.

Comment: this works great. Thanks so much for lending your expertise! Now I have to work on my ajax command to return the JSON object

Comment: one more thing, if I have multiple records being returned, I will create a loop to iterate through each `json.hits.hits[0,1,2...]`, will I use the same format as you referenced above? for example: `for(i=0,i<=json.hits.hits.len, i++) { data.rows = [...etc`

Comment: Yep, then you can do something like: `data.rows.push({"c": [{"v": json.hits.hits[i]._source_lane}, ... ]});`

Comment: pushing a new line to the json rows is not working as expected.  I believe the format must be wrong. I updated the original post with my code.

Comment: Can you post the JSON you're generating that is wrong? Curious what it looks like. The code you posted seems ok to me.

Comment: Figured out the issuse... the JSON was fine, however the numbers were stored as strings causing some issues.  I used parseInt on the number rows and it works great.  Thanks for your help.